# updating specific array in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Tournament collection in my Mongo and within it there is a document "Edition 6". In this document there is an array field that looks like this:-

```
TeamDetails[0]:
[
TeamName : Team 1,
TeamOwner : Name,
]
TeamDetails[1]:
[
TeamName : Team 2,
TeamOwner : Name
]
```

There are a total of 10 such elements in the Teamdetails array. With each element having the teamname field as unique. Is there anyway I can update only one element using a query to identify based on the team name?

Just before the update I have a set of variables that are coming into this module with data. I want to update those variables into a specific array matching the teamname. I know about using the $push operator, but how do i specifically query to update that element out of the 10. Is this possible? I am using mongoose with Node js

Answer (score 0):

Your **Tournament** collection like:

```
_id: 123456

TeamDetails: [

  {
    TeamName : Team 1,
    TeamOwner : Name,
  },
  {
    TeamName : Team 2,
    TeamOwner : Name,
  }

]
```

```
Tournament.updateOne({ _id: 123456, 'TeamDetails.TeamName': 'Team 1' }, 
                     { '$set': { 'TeamDetails.$.TeamOwner': 'Hello'} });
```

Result Will be:

```
_id: 123456

TeamDetails: [

  {
    TeamName : Team 1,
    TeamOwner : Hello,
  },
  {
    TeamName : Team 2,
    TeamOwner : Name,
  }

]
```

For more details you can read in [this doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)